# working with a lot of JAVA serialized objects

Tags: java, serialization

I have 10,000,000 JAVA serialized objects that each serialized object is a small file but all the 10 million files are in a folder and working on that folder is so hard, (It take a lot of time to open the folder and read each file).
Do you have any suggestion to work easier and faster with my files?
assume that each object is a person that have some attributes like id, name, age, city, address, and ... .

Comment: You can generally write multiple objects to a single file. How to do this, how to group them (or whether to put them all in one file) and how many objects to put in each file will depend on your implementation. I doubt we can offer more specific advice without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: This seems to beg for some sort of database instead of single object files.

Comment: Have you already thought about storing this files in database?

Comment: @Kayaman, I already use a database, but I need to work with files too.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to serialization. It's slow because, as you say, "It take a lot of time to open the folder and read each file". If you really must use multiple files, then you can create subdirectories based on the first letters of the file name - or on first digits of the hash of the file name, in order to keep the number of files per directory within limits in which the filesystem can efficiently search directories.

Answer (score 0):

I am imagining that a lot of the time is spent in opening the file.  Even with a modern OS, and a decent file system, and a SSD, opening a file is a relatively expensive operation (as opposed to reading from a file that is already open).

See if you can serialize all of your objects into one file, and compare the read time with the many file approach.

Comment: Honestly, there are so many unmentioned things in your question, that this is somewhat of an "educated shot in the dark".  If the contents of each file is complex, it might not be this.

Comment: @edvin you're right, each object is a complex object, and fast accessing to each file is important

Comment: @SajjadDehqani Often one can find faster solutions to indexing than creating one file for each item and storing them in the file system with the directory as the index.  But, before you go about trying new techniques and then discovering the performance; have you actually bench marked the portions of your current solution?  It would be a shame for you to improve a component that takes 1% of your time to 0.1% of your time, when another is taking 95% of your time.

Comment: Thanks For Your ADVICE.

Comment: @SajjadDehqani You're welcome.  I hope you find your slow step, and it is easy to make faster.

Answer (score 0):

Java's standard serialisation is known to be slow -

[KST](http://ruedigermoeller.github.io/fast-serialization/) could be of great use to you and also provides tools for offheap reading/writing.

Have a look and see if you can use it as it has been proven to be up to 10 times faster than the standard.